# Can I get Mac Java Edition for free after buying Windows Java Edition?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I bought Windows Java Edition and wanted Minecraft on my Mac. Will I get the Mac Java Edition free because I bought the Windows Java Edition, or do I have to buy it?

Answer (score 6):

Since Java edition is linked to your Minecraft account, and there are multiple versions on the site for download, yes. You can get Java edition for free (as long as you log into the Minecraft account that purchased it).

But if the same account is in-play, it will either:

- log the current player out, or
- deny you access.

Comment: Yep, you can have as many installations on as many systems as you like, just one of them can be logged in at a time to play online. You can actually start multiple single-player games with the same account simultaneously (although I'm not sure if you're legally permitted to do so, anyway, the game won't stop you).

Answer (score 1):

Minecraft Java Edition covers all platforms that Java runs on, so... Yes.

Including Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Minecraft Java Edition works on Windows, Mac, and Linux. You can install Java Edition again for free only if you use the same account as the one you used to install Java Edition for Windows.